# How can i delete starting white spaces using perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

What's the way to indicate white spacess in perl ?
How can i delete starting spaces using perl regular expressions?

Answer (score 6):

```
my $foo = " \t\n\r  hello, world!";
$foo =~ s/^\s+//;    # This is the line that removes the leading whitespace.
print "$foo\n";
print ord($foo) . "\n";
```

Will display:

```
hello, world!
104
```

104 is the ASCII character code for `h`, proving that the string has no leading whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

This searches for repeated whitespaces (`\s+`) at the beginning of the string (`^`), substituting with nothing (i.e. what is between the delimiters here: `//`):

```
$myString =~ s/^\s+//;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp = "   Hello world";
#print $temp;
$temp =~ s/^\s+//;
print $temp;
```